# Correct syntax to pass get request parameter value by using EL

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to pass value by using EL expression in get request parameter, but I'm getting empty value of request parameter whenever I click on that URL. Could anyone please tell me the correct syntax?

```
<c:forEach var="message" items="${requestScope.inboxmessage}" varStatus="messageCount" >
     <a href="just.do?value="+${messageCount.count} >
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use EL, you don't need to worry about concatenating Strings like that.

Try this: `<a href="just.do?value=${messageCount.count}">`

You might also want to look at the `<c:out>` tag, it'll take care of things like escaping illegal characters.